# How to deploy a GWT application in the Ibm Websphere 7

Tags: gwt, websphere

We have created gwt application on eclipse juno 4.2 and gwt 2.5.1 and exported the application as war file using GWT Web App Export. Added the war file to the EAR project
of the eclipse. 
If I deploy it on the websphere through eclipse it gets deployed. But if I try to deploy the same ear file through the admin console of WAS , the process hangs, I have tried all
the suggestions available over the net but all in vain.
Can anybody throw some light on this and provide guidence.

Thanks

Bhavani

Comment: What is the size of the application? Did you check server logs?

Comment: Definitely check the server logs. Look in the WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/profile-name/logs/server-name/SystemOut.log and SystemErr.log files.

Comment: please add exception in the logs if any

Answer (score 0):

Now I am able to deploy it through Websphere console.

Thanks for (fnt) by specifying about the size of the application.
When I posted the question the size of the war/ear was 111MB ,I removed 
all the jar files and placed it in Websphere app servers ext foloder and
I build the war file through GWT compiler to contain only the binary codes of sources required for the application. The size was reduced to 7MB (the previous war file was
having jasper jars which was accounting for the most of the size)

Then I deployed the ear file through the admin console. Still It almost took
more than 20 minutes to deploy it through the admin console and I am
successfully able to deploy it and aceess the GWT application.

Thanks

Bhavani

Comment: You might need to increase heap size for WAS instance to reduce deployment time.